# how to run a c# method from js inside of the webview app in xamarin

Tags: javascript, c#, android, xamarin

I have a problem with running a c# method from js that is inside of a webview in xamarin.

I have a c# method like this:

```cs
public void simpleMethod(int a,string b,bool c){
string[] data;
if(c){
data[a] = b;
}
}
```

Now how do I call this method from the javasript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a **Custom Renderer** of `WebView`

> Create a custom WebView in Forms

```
public class HybridWebView : View
{
  Action<int, string, bool> action;
  public static readonly BindableProperty UriProperty = BindableProperty.Create (
    propertyName: "Uri",
    returnType: typeof(string),
    declaringType: typeof(HybridWebView),
    defaultValue: default(string));

  public string Uri {
    get { return (string)GetValue (UriProperty); }
    set { SetValue (UriProperty, value); }
  }

  public void RegisterAction (Action<int, string, bool> callback)
  {
    action = callback;
  }

  public void Cleanup ()
  {
    action = null;
  }

  public void InvokeAction (int a,string b,bool c)
  {
    if (action == null ) {
      return;
    }
    action.Invoke (a,b,c);
  }
}
```

> in ContentPage

The HybridWebView instance will be used to display a native web control on each platform. It's Uri property is set to an HTML address , and which will be displayed by the native web control.

The HybridWebViewPage registers the action to be invoked from JavaScript, as shown in the following code example:

```
public partial class xxxPage : ContentPage
{
  public xxxPage ()
  {
    //...
    hybridWebView.RegisterAction ((a,b,c) => simpleMethod(a,b,c));
  }

  public void simpleMethod(int a,string b,bool c)
  {
     string[] data;
     if(c){
        data[a] = b;
      }
  }

}
```

```
<ContentPage.Content>
   <local:HybridWebView x:Name="hybridWebView" Uri="https://learn.microsoft.com"
          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
</ContentPage.Content>
```

> in your html file

For example you want to call the method when click a button

```
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:invokeCSCode(a,b,c);">Invoke C# Code</button>
//...

<script type="text/javascript">

function invokeCSCode(a,b,c) {
    try {

        invokeCSharpAction(a,b,c);
    }
    catch (err){
          log(err);
    }
}
```

> Creating the Custom Renderer on iOS

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof(HybridWebView), typeof(HybridWebViewRenderer))]
namespace CustomRenderer.iOS
{
    public class HybridWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<HybridWebView, WKWebView>, IWKScriptMessageHandler
    {
        const string JavaScriptFunction = "function invokeCSharpAction(a,b,c){window.webkit.messageHandlers.invokeAction.postMessage(a,b,c);}";
        WKUserContentController userController;

        protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<HybridWebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged (e);

            if (e.OldElement != null) {
                userController.RemoveAllUserScripts ();
                userController.RemoveScriptMessageHandler ("invokeAction");
                var hybridWebView = e.OldElement as HybridWebView;
                hybridWebView.Cleanup ();
            }
            if (e.NewElement != null) {
                if (Control == null) {
                    userController = new WKUserContentController ();
                    var script = new WKUserScript (new NSString (JavaScriptFunction), WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentEnd, false);
                    userController.AddUserScript (script);
                    userController.AddScriptMessageHandler (this, "invokeAction");

                    var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration { UserContentController = userController };
                    var webView = new WKWebView (Frame, config);
                    SetNativeControl (webView);
                }

                Control.LoadRequest (new NSUrlRequest (new NSUrl (Element.Uri, false)));
            }
        }

        public void DidReceiveScriptMessage (WKUserContentController userContentController, WKScriptMessage message)
        {
            Element.InvokeAction (message.Body.ToString ());
        }
    }
}
```

In addition, **Info.plist** must be updated to include the following values:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

> Creating the Custom Renderer on Android

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(HybridWebView), typeof(HybridWebViewRenderer))]
namespace CustomRenderer.Droid
{
    public class HybridWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<HybridWebView, Android.Webkit.WebView>
    {
        const string JavascriptFunction = "function invokeCSharpAction(a,b,c){jsBridge.invokeAction(a,b,c);}";
        Context _context;

        public HybridWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<HybridWebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                Control.RemoveJavascriptInterface("jsBridge");
                var hybridWebView = e.OldElement as HybridWebView;
                hybridWebView.Cleanup();
            }
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                if (Control == null)
                {
                    var webView = new Android.Webkit.WebView(_context);
                    webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                    webView.SetWebViewClient(new JavascriptWebViewClient($"javascript: {JavascriptFunction}"));
                    SetNativeControl(webView);
                }
                Control.AddJavascriptInterface(new JSBridge(this), "jsBridge");
                Control.LoadUrl(Element.Uri);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class JavascriptWebViewClient : WebViewClient
{
    string _javascript;

    public JavascriptWebViewClient(string javascript)
    {
        _javascript = javascript;
    }

    public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
    {
        base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
        view.EvaluateJavascript(_javascript, null);
    }
}
```

```
public class JSBridge : Java.Lang.Object
{
  readonly WeakReference<HybridWebViewRenderer> hybridWebViewRenderer;

  public JSBridge (HybridWebViewRenderer hybridRenderer)
  {
    hybridWebViewRenderer = new WeakReference <HybridWebViewRenderer> (hybridRenderer);
  }

  [JavascriptInterface]
  [Export ("invokeAction")]
  public void InvokeAction (int a,string b,bool c)
  {
    HybridWebViewRenderer hybridRenderer;

    if (hybridWebViewRenderer != null && hybridWebViewRenderer.TryGetTarget (out hybridRenderer))
    {
      hybridRenderer.Element.InvokeAction (a,b,c);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could Xamarin implement this by default? It would be nice it would be nice to have something like [Cefsharp's JS Interaction](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/07ac50064bd9c6460ca2effcb2bfc0d5eb2080d6/CefSharp.Wpf.Example/JavascriptCallbackMainWindow.xaml.cs#L12) without having to add any code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. 
Basically you have to detect / trigger a piece of javascript code, detect it with your C# webview configuration/initialization code, and then execute your C#.

Take a look at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/JavascriptInterface for android to understand what I'm saying, and implement it on Android.
For iOS you have a WKWebview listener that you can use to receive informations from your webpage.